# If I have a patent in china, can I also apply for a US patent?

Tags: patent-applications, us, utility-patent

My Chinese patent is good for another 5 years. Can i apply for US patent in the meantime if i plan to sell the product in the US?

Answer (score 1):

If you have 5 years left, that implies that the application date of your Chinese patent was 15 years ago.

In that case, you are too late to obtain another patent for the same invention in another country. This needs to be done within 12 months of the first filing date (the priority date if priority is claimed, the filing date otherwise).